# How to store ratio values in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I want to display user inputs and render them as new inputs are in. But currently, I can't seem to find a way to store the ratio values of multiple selections. I have tried "bind.(this)" and etc. None worked :(

Here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Input extends Component {
    state = {
        nameItems: [],
        ageItems: [],
        statusItems: [],

        nameInput: '',
        ageInput: '',
        statusInput: ''
    }

    nameChangeHandler = ({target:{value}}) => this.setState({
        nameInput: value
    })

    ageChangeHandler = ({target:{value}}) => this.setState({
        ageInput: value
    })


    submitHandler = e =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
        nameItems: [...this.state.nameItems, this.state.nameInput],
        ageItems: [...this.state.ageItems, this.state.ageInput],
        statusItems: [...this.state.statusItems, this.state.statusInput],
        nameInput: '',
        ageInput: '',
        statusInput: ''
        })
    }    


    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <h1>User signup form</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value={this.state.nameInput} onChange={this.nameChangeHandler} /><br />
            <label for="age">Age:</label><br />
            <input type="number" id="age" name="age" value={this.state.ageInput} onChange={this.ageChangeHandler}/><br />

            <div class="schoolYear">
            <p>Your status:</p>
            <input type="radio" id="freshman" name="status" value="freshman" />
            <label for="freshman">Freshman</label><br />
            <input type="radio" id="css" name="status" value="sophomore" />
            <label for="sophomore">Sophomore</label><br />
            <input type="radio" id="junior" name="status" value="junior" />
            <label for="junior">Junior</label><br />
            <input type="radio" id="senior" name="status" value="senior"  />
            <label for="senior">Senior</label><br />
            </div>
            
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
     

            <ul>
            {
                this.state.nameItems.map((key) => <li>{key}</li>) 
            }
            {
                this.state.ageItems.map((key) => <li>{key}</li>)
            }
            {
                this.state.statusItems.map((key) => <li>{key}</li>)
            }
            </ul>

            </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Input;
```

I have tried using the onChange on each individual option and the whole div but still can seem to obtain the radio value. Also when I tried setting "checked" the whole program seems to end up in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just Copied Your code .
First of All , if you want to multiple select radio , don't name it as the same.

```
<div class="schoolYear">
    <p>Your status:</p>
    <input type="radio" id="freshman" name="freshman" value="freshman" onChange={(event)=>{setStatus((prev)=>[...prev,event.currentTarget.value])}}/>
    <label for="freshman">Freshman</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="css" name="css" value="sophomore" onChange={(event)=>{setStatus((prev)=>[...prev,event.currentTarget.value])}}/>
    <label for="sophomore">Sophomore</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="junior" name="junior" value="junior" onChange={(event)=>{setStatus((prev)=>[...prev,event.currentTarget.value])}}/>
    <label for="junior">Junior</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="senior" name="senior" value="senior"  onChange={(event)=>{setStatus((prev)=>[...prev,event.currentTarget.value])}}/>
    <label for="senior">Senior</label><br />
    </div>
```